# DynamoDB: find item by Global Secondary Index using Spring Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data

In my project, I want to fetch data by GSI. And my GSI is such that it will always be unique, so it will return at most one item at a time. But when I used **@DynamoDBIndexHashKe**y annotation on the field that I have made GSI, I get a **ResourceNotFoundException:**

> "Exception:  | Exception : class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException | Exception message : Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException;"

But if I only use @DynamoDBAttribute which is to say only defines the column, everything works fine.

Repository:

```java
@EnableScan
public interface MyRepository extends DynamoDBCrudRepository< MyModel, String> {

MyModel findByMetaData(String metaData);
MyModel findByPrimaryKey(String primaryKey);
}
```

Model:

```java
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my_model")
public class MyModel {

   @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "primary_key")
   @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "primary_key")
   private String primaryKey;

   @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "meta_data", globalSecondaryIndexName = "meta_data")
   @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "meta_data")
   private String metaData;
```

And this is how DynamoDB client is being created.

```java
@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider,
                                     @Value("${aws.region}") String region) {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
        .withRegion(region)
        .build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DynamoDBMapper mapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB,
                             @Value("${table.name.prefix}") String tableNamePrefix) {
    DynamoDBMapperConfig config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().
        withTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix(tableNamePrefix + "-"))
        .build();
    return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, config);
}
```

Also find by primary partition key is working fine.

I have created a secondary index "meta_data" on my table too.

[image: AWS Console]

So is there a problem in code or in the way I have created global secondary index in AWS?

Comment: Sure I have changed it now